# How to assert that a function is called with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I'm learning double tests with a simple example:

```
const Database = require('./Database')

const setupNewUser = (info, callback) => {
    const user = {
        name: info.name,
        nameLowercase: info.name.toLowerCase()
    }

    try {
        Database.save(user, callback)
    } catch (err) {
        callback(err)
    }
}

module.exports = setupNewUser
```

I have a function that takes an object and a callback:

```
const Database = {
    save: (user, callback) => {
        callback(user)
    }
}
module.exports = Database
```

How can test that `save` is called with both an object and a callback. Below is what I'm trying:

```
it('it calls Database.save with a callback', () => {
    const saveSpy = sinon.spy(Database, 'save')
    const arg = {
        name: info.name,
        nameLowercase: info.name.toLowerCase()
    }
    setupNewUser(info, function() {})

    //I'm able to assert that save is called with arg sinon.assert.calledWith(saveSpy, arg)
    sinon.assert.calledWith(saveSpy, arg, function() {}) //This is failing
})
```

Comment: I just tried using a spy as callback and it seems to work. 
`const callback = sinon.spy()` and I used it as a callback in `setupNewUser(info, callback)`. Then `sinon.assert.calledWith(saveSpy, arg, callback)` seems to work. 

Am I doing the right thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `.stub` your API calls vs `.spy`. I would also recommend using `sinon.sandbox` so your test cleanup is easy to manage. Read about it [here](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.0.0/sandbox/)

```
describe('Setup new user', function() {
  const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

  afterEach(function() {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should call Database.save with a callback', function(){
    const databaseSaveStub = sandbox.stub(Database, 'save');

    const user = {
      name: 'Some Name',
      nameLowercase: 'some name'
    };

    const callbackFn = sandbox.spy();

    setupNewUser(user, callbackFn);

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(Database.save);        
    sinon.assert.calledWith(databaseSaveStub, user, callbackFn);
  });
});
```